# I get same url for multiple file on Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

When I try to send file to Firebase Storage and getDownloadUrl for each files, I notice that all file are upload but I get the url of last File.

This is the function.

```
var files = this.state.image
var image, fileExtension, imageName, uploadTask

for (var i = 0; i < this.state.image.length; i++) {
  image = files[i]
  console.log(this.state.image)



  fileExtension = '.' + image.name.split('.').pop();
  imageName = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) + new Date().getTime() + [i] + fileExtension
  uploadTask[i] = storage.ref(`images/${imageName}`).put(image);
  console.log(imageName)

  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    snapshot => {
      // progress function ...
      const progress = Math.round(
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      );
      this.setState({ progress });
    },
    error => {
      // Error function ...
      toast('ldjddkj')
      console.log(error);
    },
    async () => {
      // complete function ...
      await storage
        .ref("images")
        .child(imageName)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(imgUrl => {
          console.log(imgUrl)
          this.setState((prevState) => ({
            imgUrl: [...prevState.imgUrl,
              imgUrl

            ],


          }
          ))
          console.log(this.state.imgUrl)
        })

    }
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
uploadTask.on(
  "state_changed",
  (snapshot) => {
    // progress function ...
    const progress = Math.round(
      (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
    );
    this.setState({ progress });
  },
  (error) => {
    // Error function ...
    toast("ldjddkj");
    console.log(error);
  }
);
uploadTask
  .then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  })
  .then((imgUrl) => {
    storage
      .ref("images")
      .child(imageName)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((imgUrl) => {
        console.log(imgUrl);
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          imgUrl: [...prevState.imgUrl, imgUrl],
        }));
        console.log(this.state.imgUrl);
      });
  });
```